# Cleardot.gif in Gmail?

Tags: google-chrome, email, gmail, privacy, tracking

I had recently read up on how people can track when someone has read a gmail message using tracking pixels they either make themselves, or with the use of chrome extensions. When I entered the network tab while using inspect element on an email someone had sent me, a successful GET request for a 'cleardot.gif' image had popped up. Is this a tracking pixel that the sender of the message is using to track me? If so, what can they find out? Or is this just a Google thing?

Either way, is there a way to find out when someone *is* personally using a tracking pixel on you? Can you highlight the 1x1 image or something/another method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an email client.  For example, on Android, I use FairMail (I am not associated with it).  By default, it blocks all images and identifies likely tracking images.  You can then choose to open each one or all of them.

[image]

Similarly, Thunderbird does this. And you can use the Options dropdown to view all the images if you so wish.

[image]